# Does Mage Hand work with Spare the Dying?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, cantrips

If you order your [mage hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand) to be touching someone, and then next turn ready [spare the dying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spare-the-dying), so if the person your mage had is touching falls to 0 hp, will they live?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/183613/can-i-use-mage-hand-as-a-third-hand-for-casting-spells-or-receiving-item-buffs/183615#183615

Answer (score 26):

### Mage Hand cannot deliver touch spells

Mage Hand's description states:

> You can use the hand to manipulate an object, open an unlocked door or container, stow or retrieve an item from an open container, or pour the contents out of a vial. You can move the hand up to 30 feet each time you use it.
>
> The hand can't attack, activate magic items, or carry more than 10 pounds.

The hand is not an extension of your body, and it does not state you can deliver touch spells through it, like for example *Find Familiar* does, which states:

> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell.

There is no such text in *Mage Hand*. Therefore you cannot deliver touch spells through it, whether *Spare the Dying* or any other spell.

Comment: I’ve reversed my downvote because I didn’t remember why I initially downvoted.

Answer (score 15):

#### Features that allow you to circumvent the “touch” requirement of spells tell that you can.

There are several features that allow you to cast a touch spell from a distance. The Trickster Cleric’s Invoke Duplicity:

> For the duration, you can cast spells as though you were in the illusion’s space

This feature allows you to cast a spell as though you were in the duplicate’s space, which allows you to touch a creature that the real you isn’t actually standing next to. We also have the Sorcerer’s Distant Spell Metamagic:

> When you cast a spell that has a range of touch, you can spend 1 sorcery point to make the range of the spell 30 feet.

And finally, the *find familiar* spell:

> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell.

These features explicitly change how touch spells work, either by changing your relative location for the purposes of casting the spell, or by changing the spell’s range directly.

*Mage hand* doesn’t do anything like this, so it cannot deliver a touch spell for you.